# An android app using SQLite Database gets stopped once a button pressed

Tags: android, sqlite

My problem is that when i press save or load button ,the app crash.

log cat

```
    E/ AndroidRuntime(4101):  FATAL EXCEPTION:   main
    E /AndroidRuntime(4101):android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
    mytable:while compiling: INSERT INTO mytable(email, name) VALUES(?, ?);
    E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime(4101):atandroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
    E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
    E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
    E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
E/AndroidRuntime(4101):android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1150)
E/AndroidRuntime(4101):atandroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1576)
E/AndroidRuntime(4101):atandroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1456)
    E/AndroidRuntime(4101): at com.databasedemo.DataHandler.insertData(DataHandler.java:65)
     E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at com.databasedemo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
     E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
     E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
     E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
     E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
     E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
     E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(4101):atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    E/AndroidRuntime(4101):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    E/AndroidRuntime(4101): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is MainActivity.java

```
  package com.databasedemo;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   Button save,load;
EditText name,email;
DataHandler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    save =(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    load=(Button) findViewById(R.id.load);
    email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String getName=name.getText().toString();
            String getEmail=email.getText().toString(); 
            handler=new DataHandler(getBaseContext());
            handler.open();
            long id=handler.insertData(getName, getEmail);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "DATA INSERTED",      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        handler.close();
        }


    });

    load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getName,getEmail;
            getName="";
            getEmail="";

        handler=new DataHandler(getBaseContext());
            handler.open();
            Cursor c=handler.returnData();
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do{
                    getName=c.getString(0);
                    getEmail=c.getString(1);

                }while(c.moveToNext());
            }
            handler.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Name:"+getName+" Email:"+getEmail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

DatabaseHandler .Java

```
   package com.databasedemo;

   import android.content.ContentValues;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.SQLException;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
   import android.database.*;
        public class DataHandler {
   public static final String NAME="name";
   public static final String EMAIL="email";
   public static final String TABLE_NAME="mytable";
   public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME="mydatabase";
   public static final int DATABSE_VERSION=1;
     public static final String TABLE_CREATE="create table mytable(name text not null,email text        not null;)";
 DataBaseHelper dbhelper;
 Context ctx;
 SQLiteDatabase db;
  public DataHandler(Context ctx)
{
this.ctx=ctx;
dbhelper=new DataBaseHelper(ctx);
 }
   private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public DataBaseHelper(Context ctx)
{
    super(ctx,DATA_BASE_NAME,null,1);
} 

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try{
db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);

}
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion , int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable");
    onCreate(db);
}
   }
   public DataHandler open()
  {
db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
return this;
   }
  public void close()
  {
 dbhelper.close();
   }
  public long insertData(String name,String email){
 ContentValues content=new ContentValues();
 content.put(NAME,name);
 content.put(EMAIL, email);
 return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, content);
   }
  public Cursor returnData()
  {
return db.query(TABLE_NAME,new String[]{NAME,EMAIL},null,null,null,null,null);
   }

   }
```

Below is activity_main.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:hint="Enter Email Here"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/load"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Save" 
    android:minWidth="120dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/load"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/save"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Load"
    android:minWidth="120dp"
    android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Name Here" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Create Table SQL command` is wrong. Correct your `Create Table SQL command` with below.

```
   public static final String TABLE_CREATE="create table mytable(name text not null, email text not null);";
```

and because of this you got error there no `Table` created in your `Database`.

> ```
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
> mytable:while compiling: INSERT INTO mytable(email, name) VALUES(?, ?);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your Create table syntax

```
public static final String TABLE_CREATE = 
"create table mytable 
( name text not null, 
email text not null;)";   // remove this ; after the null word
```

is wrong, the correct syntax should be like below,

```
public static final String TABLE_CREATE = 
"create table mytable 
( name text not null, 
email text not null );";
```

Comment: ,changed but still app get crash

Comment: remove your old and and install the fresh one.

Comment: Are you sure that problem is in create table syntax only ,i have changed the syntax as stated by you ,but still the same problem. please help me ,check if there is any other problem ,if so.

Answer (score 0):

try this for create table,

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (name TEXT NOT NULL,email TEXT NOT NULL);"
```